# Unable to pass a variable through an ajax request

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I'am trying to pass a parameter using ajax to another php page and view the passed parameter in there. But its only redirecting page.parameter is not passed

This is my form.Used to get name through input field

```
<form id="regform" method="post" action="">
    <div>
        First Name:
        <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />    
        <input type="submit" class="color" name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn" value="register" />
    </div>
</form>
```

This is the ajax code I'am using pass my parameter to ajax.php page.

```
            $("#regform").submit(function(e) {
                e.preventDefault();
                var form = $(this);
                //var url = form.attr('action');
                var senddata = {"fname": $('#fname').val()};
                console.log(senddata);
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    contentType: "application/json",
                    url: "ajax.php",
                    dataType: 'json',
                    data: JSON.stringify(senddata),
                    success: function(data) {
                        console.log(data);
                    }
                });
```

Comment: Try changing ``senddata`` to ``$("#regform").serialize()`` because it's more concise, it will capture all of your form fields, and the way you're setting ``senddata`` now and then stringifying the JSON is unnecessarily complicated and error-prone. It would help to see you php code as well to see how you're attempting to access the variables.

Comment: ok I will try. thankyou

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this.it is working.

```
<head>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    </head>
    <form id="regform" method="post" action="">
        <div>
            First Name:
            <input type="text" name="fname" id="fname" />
            <input type="submit" class="color" name="loginBtn" id="loginBtn" value="register" />
        </div>
    </form>
    <script>
     $("#regform").submit(function(e) {
                    e.preventDefault();
                    var senddata = $('#fname').val();
                    console.log(senddata);
                    $.ajax({
                        type: "post",
                        url: "ajax.php",
                        dataType: 'json',
                        data: {fname:senddata},
                        success: function(data) {
                            console.log(data);
                        }
                    });
                    });
            </script>
```

PHP

```
<?php
echo ($_POST['fname']);
?>
```

Comment: Can you please tell me how to send multiple data through this ?

Comment: As you can see {fname:senddata}, if you want to send  more data then {fname:senddata, lname:sendlname, phone:phoneNumber} put the comma and send multiple data